# Getting the IP External address, and putting it on login

Tags: c#

I've been trying to make out one function, which should work like:

The user turned on the app (Winform C#), and they're trying to login to a form, with login & Register function, and the app is getting their IP-address with this function:

```
 private string Gaunamip()
    {
        string ip = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");
        ip = ip.Replace("\n", "");
        return ip;
    }
```

And I tried to make a function which will get their IP, and check if it's been confirmed. I mean confirmed in the script. I have a list which allows a few IPs, and let the user login. I've made something like this:

```
string ClientIP = Gaunamip();
        if (!ClientIP.StartsWith("85.206.158.0"))
        {
            // Jeigu neprasideda
            label6.Text = "\n IP Not Registered";
            label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        }
        else
        {
            //  MessageBox.Show("IP Accepted, welcome");
            label6.Text = "\n IP Accepted";
            label6.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            //Proceed with Execution
        }
```

**My Question**: *How could I make a line which checks the few IP But not a single one.*

Comment: Are you sure you're doing this right? There's not enough information in your question, but shouldn't a server be checking this? I mean, what's to stop me opening up the client EXE, changing the list of valid IP addresses, rebuilding, and then loading it up?

Comment: Not if you sign your `EXE`

Answer (score 0):

You can create array of allowed ips like:

```
var allowedAddresses = new[] {"192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", ...};
```

and then check if array contains your address

```
if(allowedAddresses.Contains(clientIP)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the ip address starts with any of the allowed ip addresses with a lambda expression:

```
    var allowedAddresses = new string[] { "85.206.158.0", "27.226.146.8" };
    if(!allowedAddresses.Any(ip => ClientIP.StartsWith(ip))) {
        // not allowed
    } else {
        // allowed
    }
```

If you just want to check if the list of allowed addresses contains the client id exactly, you can use `allowedAddresses.Contains(ClientId)`